# On page refresh images load randomly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

On page refresh images load randomly. Here images are loading in sequence. I'm trying to load images randomly on page refresh. And I don't want to change the HTML structure. Images are adding through the frontend I can't add in js. Can anyone suggest to me how to achieve.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.randomSlider ul.fader li').hide();
  $('.randomSlider ul.fader li').css('position', 'absolute');
  $('.randomSlider ul.fader li').css('top', '0px');
  $('.randomSlider ul.fader li').css('left', '0px');

  var max = $('.randomSlider ul.fader li').length;

  function showSlider() {

    if (localStorage.slider) {
      $('.randomSlider .fader').find('li:nth(' + localStorage.slider + ')').fadeIn();
      localStorage.slider = parseInt(localStorage.slider, 10) + 1;
      if (localStorage.slider >= max) localStorage.slider = 0;
    } else {
      $('.randomSlider .fader').find('li:nth(0)').fadeIn();
      localStorage.slider = 1;
    }
  }

  showSlider();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="randomSlider">
  <ul class="fader">
    <li data-id="1"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/10/03/04/21/woman-6676901_960_720.jpg"></li>
    <li data-id="2"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/08/23/04/02/woman-6566600_960_720.jpg"></li>
    <li data-id="3"> <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/26/14/27/sparrow-5604220_960_720.jpg"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: So, what did you try? This code just seems a textbook example, and you are looking for somebody to write the change for you?

Comment: @Icepickle Here I'm trying to load images randomly but I don't want to change the HTML structure.

Comment: Are you meaning loading randomly or do you mean showing them in random order in the slider? Actual loading is probably beyond your control given the system may be using caching.

Comment: @AHaworth Show random images on every page refresh. like 1,3,2 and 3,1,2 in random order

Comment: Have you investigated JavaScript Math.random function? Try that and put the resulting code in your question if you are still stuck.

Comment: @AHaworth i understand but how to fetch attr data-id in an array to add images.

Comment: If you can’t use JS then I don’t think you can do this.

Comment: You wan to do this in your plugin, browser plugin ? could you provide more deail?

Comment: @emptyhua custom elementor plugin which I was already developed that's why I was unable to change HTML structure. Only using js I want to achieve the output.

Comment: @Husna Can you change backend? You can create one api give random images.

Comment: @Armin No, it is not possible via js?

Comment: js is the frontend, backed should use php or node.js or something else.

Comment: @Armin Yes it is ok if this login in php

Answer (score 1):

You can put all `img` `src` in an array and then generate a random number to get value from array on load

```js
myarray = ["https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/10/03/04/21/woman-6676901_960_720.jpg", "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/08/23/04/02/woman-6566600_960_720.jpg", "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/26/14/27/sparrow-5604220_960_720.jpg"]
window.onload = function(){
 var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
 var randomImgSrc = document.getElementById("myRandomImg").src = myarray[randomNum];
 console.log(randomNum)
}
```

```html
<img src="" id="myRandomImg">
```

Comment: I don't want to change the HTML structure because I developed a plugin for this so can't change the HTML.

Comment: There is no change in your html structure just remove the extra image tags and keep one. @Husna

Comment: Yes images adding through frontend I can't add in js

Comment: @Husna, that seems to be important information missing from your OP

Answer (score 1):

For random position of elements on page we can add random item to the beginning of their container `n` times. Let `n` be `images.length`.

Here we change order of `<li>` elements, not images themselves, so the `data-id` has to be reordered (if wanted);

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const li_cont = document.querySelector('.randomSlider .fader');
    const li_items = [...li_cont.querySelectorAll('li')];
    const len = li_items.length;

    for(let i = 0; i < len; i++){
        li_cont.prepend(li_items[Math.floor(Math.random()*len)]);
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="randomSlider">
    <ul class="fader">
        <li data-id="1"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/10/03/04/21/woman-6676901_960_720.jpg"></li>
        <li data-id="2"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/08/23/04/02/woman-6566600_960_720.jpg"></li>
        <li data-id="3"> <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/26/14/27/sparrow-5604220_960_720.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Or we can get random order of all images by their num. Then reorder images in list-items. So the list-item order stay same, only images change.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const li_cont = document.querySelector('.randomSlider .fader');
    const li_items = li_cont.querySelectorAll('li');
    const images = li_cont.querySelectorAll('img');
    
    reorderImages(getRandomOrder(images.length));

    function getRandomOrder(max){
        const init_arr = [...new Array(max)].map((_,i) => i);
        const result = [];
        while(init_arr.length > 0){
            result.push(...init_arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*(init_arr.length)),1));
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    function reorderImages(order){
        li_items.forEach((li,i) => {
            li.appendChild(images[order[i]]);
        })
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="randomSlider">
    <ul class="fader">
        <li data-id="1"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/10/03/04/21/woman-6676901_960_720.jpg"></li>
        <li data-id="2"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/08/23/04/02/woman-6566600_960_720.jpg"></li>
        <li data-id="3"> <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/26/14/27/sparrow-5604220_960_720.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Or we get list of `src` attributes of images, and reassign them in random order.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const images = document.querySelectorAll('.randomSlider img');
    const sources = [...images].map(img => img.getAttribute('src'));
    
    reorderSources(getRandomOrder(images.length));

    function getRandomOrder(max){
        const init_arr = [...new Array(max)].map((_,i) => i);
        const result = [];
        while(init_arr.length > 0){
            result.push(...init_arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*(init_arr.length)),1));
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    function reorderSources(order){
        images.forEach((img,i) => {
            img.setAttribute('src', sources[order[i]]);
        })
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="randomSlider">
    <ul class="fader">
        <li data-id="1"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/10/03/04/21/woman-6676901_960_720.jpg"></li>
        <li data-id="2"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/08/23/04/02/woman-6566600_960_720.jpg"></li>
        <li data-id="3"> <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/26/14/27/sparrow-5604220_960_720.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to randomize the **order** of the images, not the **url**, you can [detach](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) and [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the `li`, then [append](https://api.jquery.com/append/) them back to the `ul`.

```js
$('.fader').append($('.fader li').detach().sort(_=>Math.random()>.5?1:-1));
```

```html
<div class="randomSlider">
  <ul class="fader">
    <li data-id="1">1<img></li>
    <li data-id="2">2<img></li>
    <li data-id="3">3<img></li>
    <li data-id="4">4<img></li>
    <li data-id="5">5<img></li>
    <li data-id="6">6<img></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `Math.random` should not be used to randomize an array.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, you should be able to query the child nodes, randomize the order and then replace the nodes with your new result.

See:

- https://api.jquery.com/children/
- https://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/

So your end result would be something like:

```
// See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
}

// Get children
var target = $("ul.fader");
var imageNodes = target.children();

// Empty parent
target.empty();

// Shuffle nodes
var shuffled = shuffleArray(imageNodes);

// Append shuffled nodes to target element
target.append(shuffled);
```

You'll want to put all of this above your `showSlider();` function.

Haven't had a chance to test this yet, but hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

So u can do this at next way:

```
$(function() {
 $.fn.shuffle = function() {
    var m = this.length,
      t, i;

    while (m) {
      i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

      t = this[m];
      this[m] = this[i];
      this[i] = t;
    }

    return this;
  };

  $("li").shuffle().each(function(index, data) {
      $(".fader").html("");
      $(".fader").append(data)
  });
});
```

As u see i create shuffle function to randomize image, after i use loop to get all images, i clear all which u have at page, and append random image from the list.

```js
$(function() {
 $.fn.shuffle = function() {
    var m = this.length,
      t, i;

    while (m) {
      i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

      t = this[m];
      this[m] = this[i];
      this[i] = t;
    }

    return this;
  };

  $("li").shuffle().each(function(index, data) {
            $(".fader").html("");
      $(".fader").append(data)
  });
});


$(function() {
  $('.randomSlider ul.fader li').hide();
  $('.randomSlider ul.fader li').css('position', 'absolute');
  $('.randomSlider ul.fader li').css('top', '0px');
  $('.randomSlider ul.fader li').css('left', '0px');

  var max = $('.randomSlider ul.fader li').length;

  function showSlider() {

    if (localStorage.slider) {
      $('.randomSlider .fader').find('li:nth(' + localStorage.slider + ')').fadeIn();
      localStorage.slider = parseInt(localStorage.slider, 10) + 1;
      if (localStorage.slider >= max) localStorage.slider = 0;
    } else {
      $('.randomSlider .fader').find('li:nth(0)').fadeIn();
      localStorage.slider = 1;
    }
  }

  showSlider();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="randomSlider">
  <ul class="fader">
    <li data-id="1"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/10/03/04/21/woman-6676901_960_720.jpg"></li>
    <li data-id="2"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/08/23/04/02/woman-6566600_960_720.jpg"></li>
    <li data-id="3"> <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/26/14/27/sparrow-5604220_960_720.jpg"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/qunzorez/j8nxew61/29/).

Answer (score 0):

```js
setInterval(function(){
 var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
 document.getElementById("demo").className  = "image" +randomNum;
 console.log(randomNum)
},3000)
```

```css
.image0 {
  left: 0px;
  width: 46px;
  background: url('http://w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif') 0 0;
}

.image1 {
  left: 63px;
  width: 43px;
  background: url('http://w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif') -47px 0;
}

.image2 {
  left: 129px;
  width: 43px;
  background: url('http://w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif') -91px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo" style="height: 44px;"></div>
```

Please check my code.

Answer (score 0):

Here i add code for get all possible shuffles and store into local storage and shuffles every time with new result until all possibility is close, after that it start with new possibility. This code is lengthy you can minify this but it works better.It gives you new result each and every time. Hope it will help you out.

```js
$(function() {
    var permute = (function() {
        return permute;

        function permute(list) {
            return list.length ?
                list.reduce(permutate, []) : [
                    []
                ];
        }

        function permutate(permutations, item, index, list) {
            return permutations.concat(permute(
                    list.slice(0, index).concat(
                        list.slice(index + 1)))
                .map(concat, [item]));
        }

        function concat(list) {
            return this.concat(list);
        }
    }());
    var currentIndex = [];
    $(".fader li").each(function(index) {
        currentIndex.push($(this).data('id'));
    });
    var originalIndex = localStorage.getItem('originalIndex');
    var possibleIndexing = localStorage.getItem('possibleIndexing');
    if (!originalIndex) {
        localStorage.setItem('originalIndex', currentIndex.toString());
    }
    if (currentIndex.toString() == originalIndex && possibleIndexing) {
        possibleIndexing = JSON.parse(possibleIndexing);
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('originalIndex', currentIndex.toString());
        permutedData = permute(currentIndex);
        possibleIndexing = permutedData;
        permutedData.map(function(value, index) {
            permutedData[index] = value.toString();
        })
        localStorage.setItem('possibleIndexing', JSON.stringify(permutedData));
    }
    if (possibleIndexing.length <= 0) {
        localStorage.setItem('originalIndex', currentIndex.toString());
        permutedData = permute(currentIndex);
        possibleIndexing = permutedData;
        permutedData.map(function(value, index) {
            permutedData[index] = value.toString();
        })
        localStorage.setItem('possibleIndexing', JSON.stringify(permutedData));
    }

    function getRndInteger(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    }

    var randomNumber = getRndInteger(0, possibleIndexing.length - 1);

    var currentShuffle = possibleIndexing[randomNumber].split(',');
    counter = 1;
    currentShuffle.map(function(value) {
        $(".fader li[data-id = " + value + "]").data('position', counter++);
    });
    $(".fader li").sort(sort_li).appendTo('.fader');

    function sort_li(a, b) {
        return ($(b).data('position')) < ($(a).data('position')) ? 1 : -1;
    }

    possibleIndexing.splice(randomNumber, 1);

    if (possibleIndexing.length <= 0) {
        localStorage.setItem('originalIndex', currentIndex.toString());
        permutedData = permute(currentIndex);
        possibleIndexing = permutedData;
        permutedData.map(function(value, index) {
            permutedData[index] = value.toString();
        })
        localStorage.setItem('possibleIndexing', JSON.stringify(permutedData));
    }
    localStorage.setItem('possibleIndexing', JSON.stringify(possibleIndexing));
    $(".randomSlider ul.fader li img").show();
});
```

```html
<style>
    .randomSlider ul.fader li {
        height: 100px;
    }

    .randomSlider ul.fader li img {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100px;
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="randomSlider">
    <ul class="fader">
        <li data-id="1" class="item"><img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/10/03/04/21/woman-6676901_960_720.jpg"></li>
        <li data-id="2" class="item my-element"><img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/08/23/04/02/woman-6566600_960_720.jpg"></li>
        <li data-id="3" class="my-element"> <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/26/14/27/sparrow-5604220_960_720.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```